# New User Page (MSO)

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

[Feedback is wanted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109751/feedback-wanted-new-user-page) on MSO for the new user page design.

Comment: Thanks for posting it, just wish we heard sooner =)

Comment: @BenBrocka, Yeah, I wonder why UX is discussed at MSO instead of here (apart from the amount of people there).

Comment: well I understand why the main thread is there, but it would be nice if we got a head's up. Meta.SO is more programmers after all.